# When calling this .pop method to an array, why am I getting an unexpected .length result

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

I'm new to JS, so please bear with me. When I tried to call the `.pop` method on an array defined as `secretMessage`, which has 24 elements, I used the syntax `secretMessage = secretMessage.pop();` I believe this is wrong. Calling the `.length method` on the array returned a value of 10, even though there were originally 24 elements. When I called the `.pop` method with the syntax `secretMessage.pop();` I had no issues and the returned `.length` value was 23. Why was this difference in syntax affecting the length of the array elements?

```
let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];

secretMessage = secretMessage.pop();
console.log(secretMessage.length); // Returns 10

secretMessage.pop();
console.log(secretMessage.length); // Returns 23 (assuming the previous mutating method is not called beforehand)
```

Comment: Using `.pop()` on an array will remove the last element from the array and _return_ the popped value. So, you are setting `secretMessage` equal to the removed/popped value from the array. I'm guessing your last element in `secretMessage` is a string which has a length of 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This changes the length of the array as expected.

The problem is that when you assign the value returned by pop to the same variable, then that variable points now to the object at the end of the array, and not longer to the array.
This an example:

```
const plants = ['broccoli', 'cauliflower', 'cabbage', 'kale', 'tomato'];
plants = plants.pop();
console.log(plants); //'tomato'
```

You can verify this by checking the following code:

```
const plants = ['broccoli', 'cauliflower', 'cabbage', 'kale', 'tomato'];
console.log(plants.pop());
// expected output: "tomato"
console.log(plants);
// expected output: Array ["broccoli", "cauliflower", "cabbage", "kale"]
plants.pop();
console.log(plants);
// expected output: Array ["broccoli", "cauliflower", "cabbage"]
```